# change details before Cakephp Auth compontent reads the database

Tags: cakephp, components, authentication

Does someone here know how to change the username before the Auth component reads the database?

The problem im having is im using mobile numbers as a login but i want to add the country code (if not present) when loggin in to my site

Any one have an idea on this?

Would be appreciated

Comment: Just to clear things up, you would like to rewrite a number like: 0410555820 to +1410555820 or 001410555280 (I'm not from the US, so these random numbers will probably not make any sense at all, nor look like a legit mobile number ;)) ?

Comment: Well im based in South Africa instead of 082xxxxxxx i want to rewrite it to 2782xxxxxxx because when I store the numbers then i need them in that format for the mobile networks networks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always extend the Auth component and do whathever you want before the asking the database :)

Something like this...

```
function login($data = null,$public = false) {
    $this->__setDefaults();
    $this->_loggedIn = false;

    if (empty($data)) {
        $data = $this->data;
    }

    if (/** query the database to check/modify the data. You could use the identify() method of the AuthComponent **/) {
        $this->Session->write($this->sessionKey, $user);
        $this->_loggedIn = true;
    }
    return $this->_loggedIn;
}
```

If you extend the auth component, remember to always use this component instead of the default Auth class. (e.g. in the AppController, the build_acl, the initdb, the beforefilter on the controllers, etc.)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much for the help

What i did was copy the core auth component and paste it into my controllers/components folder. then i customized it instead of extending it. Thanks for the idea and advice :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CakePHP 2.0, you can manipulate the login form data as usual and then call `$this->Auth->login()`. Example:

```
// in your controller
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->data['User']['username'] = $this->addCountryCode($this->data['User']['username']);

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            // login successful
        } else {
            // login not successful
        }
    }
}
```